# How to generate a tree for MLM ( Multi-Level Marketing ) in JavaScript for either JSON / XML data

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, tree, hierarchy

I have some data like this : 
(AT sql sERVER)

```
MemberID,ParemtID,Amt,OtherInfo
1,       NULL,    200,dfdsf
2,       1,       300,DFDF
3,       1,       400,DFS
4,       3,       75,NULL
```

Now I want build [Tree](http://goo.gl/sogUr) like this : 
[image]
Only using JS.
Above data can be passed in JSON / XML / CSV / Formatted Text
How can i generate such dynamic tree in JS only ?
Please don't suggest PHP / .NET solutions.
I would prefer a JQuery.

Comment: Can you please post some code. How is data received at the client side?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

And, here you go:

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/vVmcC/</strike>
http://jsfiddle.net/vVmcC/4/

You'll want to style it up yourself, obviously. But this should get you started:

```
var members = [
    {memberId : 1, parentId:null, amount:200, otherInfo:"blah"},
    {memberId : 2, parentId:1, amount:300, otherInfo:"blah1"},
    {memberId : 3, parentId:1, amount:400, otherInfo:"blah2"},
    {memberId : 4, parentId:3, amount:500, otherInfo:"blah3"},
    {memberId : 6, parentId:1, amount:600, otherInfo:"blah4"},
    {memberId : 9, parentId:4, amount:700, otherInfo:"blah5"},
    {memberId : 12, parentId:2, amount:800, otherInfo:"blah6"},
    {memberId : 5, parentId:2, amount:900, otherInfo:"blah7"},
    {memberId : 13, parentId:2, amount:0, otherInfo:"blah8"},
    {memberId : 14, parentId:2, amount:800, otherInfo:"blah9"},
    {memberId : 55, parentId:2, amount:250, otherInfo:"blah10"},
    {memberId : 56, parentId:3, amount:10, otherInfo:"blah11"},
    {memberId : 57, parentId:3, amount:990, otherInfo:"blah12"},
    {memberId : 58, parentId:3, amount:400, otherInfo:"blah13"},
    {memberId : 59, parentId:6, amount:123, otherInfo:"blah14"},
    {memberId : 54, parentId:6, amount:321, otherInfo:"blah15"},
    {memberId : 53, parentId:56, amount:10000, otherInfo:"blah7"},
    {memberId : 52, parentId:2, amount:47, otherInfo:"blah17"},
    {memberId : 51, parentId:6, amount:534, otherInfo:"blah18"},
    {memberId : 50, parentId:9, amount:55943, otherInfo:"blah19"},
    {memberId : 22, parentId:9, amount:2, otherInfo:"blah27"},
    {memberId : 33, parentId:12, amount:-10, otherInfo:"blah677"}

];
var testImgSrc = "http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/06005cd2700c136d09e71838645d36ff?s=69&d=wavatar";
(function heya( parentId ){
    // This is slow and iterates over each object everytime.
    // Removing each item from the array before re-iterating 
    // may be faster for large datasets.
    for(var i = 0; i < members.length; i++){
        var member = members[i];
        if(member.parentId === parentId){
            var parent = parentId ? $("#containerFor" + parentId) : $("#mainContainer"),
                memberId = member.memberId,
                    metaInfo = "<img src='"+testImgSrc+"'/>" + member.otherInfo + " ($" + member.amount + ")";
            parent.append("<div class='container' id='containerFor" + memberId + "'><div class='member'>" + memberId + "<div class='metaInfo'>" + metaInfo + "</div></div></div>");
            heya(memberId);
        } 
    }
 }( null ));

// makes it pretty:
// recursivley resizes all children to fit within the parent.
var pretty = function(){
    var self = $(this),
        children = self.children(".container"),
        // subtract 4% for margin/padding/borders.
        width = (100/children.length) - 2;
    children
        .css("width", width + "%")
        .each(pretty);

};
$("#mainContainer").each(pretty);
```

It is by no means an optimal solution. The first loop will become a nightmare for performance the more data you begin loading.

Comment: Thanks for answer.But can't we have a tree structure in it.yours jsfiddle link shows only linear structure.I am looking for tree structure.Looking forward for your reply soon.

Comment: Oh, right. I only tested in Chrome's dev channel. Sorry about that. IE8 probably has a problem with the margins or floats or something.

Comment: oh yah, and make sure you don't have any circular references, e.g., `var members = [{memberId:1, parentId:2},{memberId:2, parentId:1}];` as I imagine the code I gave you will enjoy locking up your browser for a while.  :-)

Comment: Can you please tell me . How can I send the data from PHP to javascript like this ??  ?

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure whether this code will run or not, I a just typing in here, without testing. And I hope this is what you are looking for. (BTW, I have conventional style for-loops for array-search. Its been long since I last used javascript. So kinda I need to refer to w3schools for the array functions. :-P)

```
var str = [
{memberID : 1, parentId:null, amount:200, otherInfo:"blah"},
{memberID : 2, parentId:1, amount:300, otherInfo:"blah1"},
{memberID : 3, parentId:1, amount:400, otherInfo:"blah2"},
{memberID : 4, parentId:3, amount:500, otherInfo:"blah3"}
];
(function fromArray(arr){
 var getElemByParent = function(parent){
  var elems = [];
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
   if (arr[i].parentId == parent)
    elems.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return elems;
 }
 var finalObj;
 var enumFunction = function(node){
  node.siblings = getElemByParent(node.memberID);
  for (var i=0;i<node.siblings.length; i++)
   enumFunction(node.siblings[i]);
 }
 finalObj = getElemByParent(null);
 enumFunction(finalObj);
 console.log(finalObj);
 return finalObj;
})(str);
```

PS: You will have to take care of many other situations as well. Like, what if the data is not consistent etc. I have avoided most(rather, all) of them in the code above.