# How can code binary mlm registration system in JavaScript node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary, registration, mlm

I am now studying in JavaScript nodejs.I know MEAN stack developer can make both frontend and backend but I have no idea how can make binary registration system by this language .Please show me some tutorials.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step you need to create Database

then create a crud system according to database

[How to generate a tree for MLM ( Multi-Level Marketing ) in JavaScript for either JSON / XML data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476442/how-to-generate-a-tree-for-mlm-multi-level-marketing-in-javascript-for-eithe)